# Testing and mocking a threaded function within a view

Tags: python, django, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a function that I run threaded within a view. Whenever I try to mock it, it always goes to the original function, no the mocked function.

The code I'm testing, from the view module:

```
def restart_process(request):
    batch_name = request.POST.get("batch_name", "")
    if batch_name:
        try:
            batch = models.Batch.objects.get(num=batch_name)
        except models.Batch.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warning("Trying to restart a batch that does not exist: " + batch_name)
            return HttpResponse(404)
        else:
            logger.info(batch_name + " restarted")
            try:
                t = threading.Thread(target=restart_from_last_completed_state, args=(batch,))
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()
            except RuntimeError:
                return HttpResponse(500, "Threading error")
            return HttpResponse(200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(400)
```

The test function:

```
class ThreadTestCases(TransactionTestCase):

def test_restart_process(self):
    client = Client()
    mock_restart_from_last_completed_state = mock.Mock()
    with mock.patch("processapp.views.restart_from_last_completed_state", mock_restart_from_last_completed_state):
        response = client.post('/batch/restart/', {"batch_name": "BATCH555"})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    mock_restart_from_last_completed_state.assert_called_once()
```

The URL:

```
url(r'^batch/restart/$', views.restart_from_last_completed_state, name="restart_batch"),
```

I always get this error:

```
ValueError: The view processapp.processing.process_runner.restart_from_last_completed_state didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I put a print command in the original function (restart_from_last_completed_state) and it always runs so the mocking does not take place.

The error seems to take the function as a view although it is not.

I'm not sure where the error is, the threading, testing, something else?

Answer (score 0):

The URL variable was wrong. Was supposed to be views.restart_process not views.restart_from_last_completed_state

A copy/paste error as so many times...